# How to compare different metrics?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, grid-search

I am using [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to tune the hyperparameters. I also would like to compare different metrics with each other:

```
def create_model(...

    model.add(Dense(,..)
    model.compile(..)
    return model

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

grid_obj  = GridSearchCV (estimator=model 
                , param_grid=hypparas
                , n_jobs=1
                , cv = 3
                , scoring = ['explained_variance', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'r2']
                , refit = 'neg_mean_squared_error'
                , return_train_score=True
                , verbose = 2
                )

grid_result = grid_obj.fit(X_train1, y_train1)
```

Afai understood is that the hyperparameters are optimized such that they fit `neg_mean_squared_error` the best. But how can I see how the other metrics behave e.g. when evaluating? Best would be if I could compare them visually.