# how to access metrics from history

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

For a regression problem I want to compare some metrics but I am only able to get `accuracy` from the history which makes no sense wrt to regression purposes. How can I get other metrics like `mean_squared_error` and so on?

```
create_model(...)
    input_layer = ...
    output_laye = ...
    model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

batch_size = [1, 2]
epochs = [1, 2]
optimizer = ['Adam', 'sgd']    
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size
                     , optimizer = optimizer
                     )

grid_obj  = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model 
                    , param_grid=hypparas
                    , n_jobs=1
                    , cv = 3
                    , scoring = ['explained_variance', 'neg_mean_squared_error', 'r2']
                    , refit = 'neg_mean_squared_error'
                    , return_train_score=True
                    , verbose = 2
                    )

grid_result = grid_obj.fit(X_train1, y_train1)

X_train1, X_val1, y_train1, y_val1 = train_test_split(X_train1, y_train1, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

grid_best = grid_result.best_estimator_
history = grid_best.fit(X_train1, y_train1
                        , validation_data=(X_val1, y_val1)
                        )

print(history.history.keys())
> dict_keys(['val_loss', 'val_accuracy', 'loss', 'accuracy'])
```

I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/50137577/6761328 to get e.g.

```
history.history['accuracy']
```

which works but I can't access `mean_squared_error` or something else:

```
history.history['neg_mean_squared_error']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-473-eb96973bf014> in <module>
----> 1 history.history['neg_mean_squared_error']

KeyError: 'neg_mean_squared_error'
```

This question is finally a follow-up on [How to compare different metrics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536084/how-to-compare-different-metrics) as I think this question is the answer to the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stand-alone Keras (not sure for the scikit-learn wrapper), `history.history['loss']` (or `val_loss` respectively for the validation set) would do the job.

Here, `'loss'` and `'val_loss'` are *keys*; give

```
print(history.history.keys())
```

to see what keys are available in your case, and you will find among them the required ones for the loss (might even be the same, i.e. `'loss'` and `'val_loss'`).

As a side note, you should remove completely `metrics=['accuracy']` from your model compilation - as you correctly point out, accuracy is meaningless in regression settings (you might want to check [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577)).

Comment: Thank you! So "loss" is basically mse or mae and so on? And I can only use of them in parallel?

Comment: @Ben yes, it is what you have used as `loss` in your model compilation (what do you mean in parallel?)

Comment: Ok, still a question. When using multiple losses, how do I know to which exactly is "loss" refering to?

Comment: @Ben You cannot use multiple *losses* in model compilation; loss is what is being optimized by the learning algorithm, and this is unique per model.

Comment: When I have the keys: "print(history.history.keys()) >
dict_keys(['val_loss', 'val_mean_squared_error', 'loss', 'mean_squared_error'])" what does this mean? is loss = mean_squared_error?

Comment: @Ben based on your `model.compile` statement, it should be. Are the values the same?